# Spacebar key not working in this particular input field

Tags: javascript

Hi so I have these tabs created by jQuery UI and I have a script that if you double click on the title of the tab, it will allow you to change the name of the tab.

Everything works including changing of the tab names..etc.  However the input field that lets me change the tab name does not allow my spacebar to work?  I have never encounter something like this before and thus coming here for help.

Here is a snippet of my code that triggers the double click to change title.

HTML:

```
<li class="tab"><a href="#tab-1" title="Cool">Cool</a><span class="hide edit-field"><input type="text" value="Cool" name="tab_title[]" placeholder="Enter Title" /><button name="edit" type="submit">Done</button></span></li>
```

JS:

```
$( '.tab' ).on( 'dblclick', 'a', function() {
  $( this ).hide();
  $( this ).siblings( '.edit-field' ).show();
} );

$( 'button[name="edit"]' ).click( function() {
   // do stuff here.
} );
```

So as previously stated everything works but just somehow the spacebar got disabled...??

Thanks to Jason Sperske, here is a fiddle that illustrates the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/YhxGd/1/

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Check if your keyboard is malfunctioning, as there is nothing in that code disabling the spacebar ?

Comment: haha...if my spacebar had issues you would see my sentences up top all jumbled together....good laugh though...

Comment: Could you provide a complete jsfiddle? I can use my spacebar here: http://jsfiddle.net/PDpyf/

Comment: @Oriol - i would but I don't know how to do it because I have jQuery tabs loaded as well..

Comment: Seriously, there's absolutely nothing in that code that would make the spacebar disabled, there ***has*** to be something we're missing.

Comment: I wanted to think that there was something wrong with the keyboard but after building a JSFiddle to try and prove my point I'm actually seeing the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/YhxGd/1/

Comment: You see, i am not crazy...thank god for that...

Comment: If you think I've faithfully implemented the code you are working with then you should add the fiddle to your question (I had to change a bit to get it working, `dblclick` instead of `dbclick`, I assumed JQuery UI 1.10.3 and I added some extra HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L181) of the source in jQuery UI:

```
case $.ui.keyCode.SPACE:
  // Activate only, no collapsing
  event.preventDefault();
  clearTimeout( this.activating );
  this._activate( selectedIndex );
  return;
```

In short, jQuery UI is intentionally preventing the space bar from preforming any action (in an attempt to give the tabs a more tab like behavior and behave less like links). As for a fix, you could attempt to disable this when you enter a tab edit mode, but I think this might give you some unintended behavior.

Comment: So does that mean it is a bad idea to have inline edit like I have it?  It is good UI I would think to do it...

Comment: I personally like your approach, but I haven't seen anyone else do it, so I'm inclined to believe that it might create more problems than it will fix.  I'm hesitant to say that It's impossible though.  There are much smarter people than me on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could keep the dblclick to edit approach but make the input appear in a modal dialog (thus not subject to the event listener)

Comment: Yeah if I have no choice...I just think it is very intuitive to double click and edit the tab right there...but again if jQuery Tabs prevents me from doing it, I have no other choice...But thank you for the quick reply and your insights on this issue...